# I am trying to show if $(x-y)(x+y) \leq 0 $ and $ (x+y) \geq 0$ then $(x-y) \leq 0$ real numbers axioms

Tags: real-analysis

This is a part of a bigger proof,

I was thinking starting with

$(x-y)(x+y) = (x-y)x + (x-y)y $ [Using distributive law]

Edit:

We also know $x \geq 0$  and $y \geq 0$

Comment: It's more convenient to work with $u = x-y$ and $v = x+y$ instead of $x$  and $y$.

Comment: Can I do that? am I allowed?

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's wrong (try $x=1, y=-1$).

Comment: Why? every inequality holds? $0 \leq 0 $

Comment: @MathWizard Not every inequality. $x -y=2 >  0$.

Comment: Which one is this? $x-y=2 > 0$

Comment: @MathWizard I've added some detail in my answer

Comment: I see, we also know $x \geq 0$  and $y \geq 0$ I forgot to write it

Answer (score 1):

If $x+y>0$ then the result is true, because it is an axiom of the real numbers that inequality is preserved by dividing by a positive quantity.

However, if $x+y=0$, the result is not true in general. Since $x+y=0$, we can choose $x-y$ to be negative and the first two inequalities will remain true. For example, as Professor Vector suggests taking $x=1$, $y=-1$ gives:

\begin{align}
(x-y)(x+y) &= 0 \\
(x+y) &= 0 \\
(x-y) &= 2
\end{align}

In other words,

\begin{align}
(x-y)(x+y) &\le 0 \\
(x+y) &\le 0 \\
(x-y) & > 0
\end{align}

which contradicts the claim.

EDIT: Since we know $x\ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, we know that if $x+y=0$, then $x=y=0$. That proves the claim.

EDIT 2: Your axioms are phrased in terms of the positive reals $P$. So let's write your statement in terms of $P$. Hopefully it is clear that you want to prove:

> If $(x-y)(x+y) \notin P$ and $-(x+y) \notin P$ then $(x-y) \notin P$.

We can prove this by contradiction like so:

> Assume $(x-y) \in P$. Then either $(x-y)(x+y) \in P$ or $-(x+y) \in P$.

By P10, either $-(x+y) \in P$ or $(x+y) \in P$ or $x+y = 0$. If $(x+y) \in P$ then by P12 $(x+y)(x-y) \in P$. So we just need to prove $x+y \ne 0$.
Well, either $y=0$ (so $x+y=x-y \in P$), or $y \in P$, so $x-y + y + y \in P$ by P11.

Comment: Sorry we also know $x \geq 0$  and $y \geq 0$

Comment: @MathWizard In that case it's true. Is my edit clear?

Comment: Not really, I need to start with $(x-y)(x+y) \leq 0 $ and $ (x+y) \geq 0$ $ x \geq 0$ $ y \geq 0$ then find $(x-y) \leq 0$ using the axioms stated here https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m524/realprop.pdf Isn't that a Real Analysis topic, did I tag wrong?

Comment: @MathWizard I see. The tag is okay, but you should probably have included the fact that your proof must use specific axioms in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have that

$$x^{2}-y^{2}\leq 0$$

so $$\vert x\vert \leq \vert y\vert$$

If $y$ is negative, then

$$x+y\leq 0$$

so it must be the case that $y>0$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: But how you did that, I need to explain every step with axioms stated here https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m524/realprop.pdf

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok, suppose the conclusion is false. Then P12 implies that $(x-y)(x+y)$ is positive, a contradiction.

Comment: I think that the second inequality has to be strict, however. You need to rule out the zero case for P12.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong in general.

Take $x=-y=1$ for a counterexample. You have

$(x-y)(x+y) = 0$, $x+y = 0$ but $x-y = 2 \gt 0$.

Comment: Ah sorry we also know $x \geq 0$  and $y \geq 0$